# Magento addToCart in product list doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, magento, e-commerce

in my

```
/app/design/frontend/{{templateName}}/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

I've got

```
<p class="action"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
```

but the `$this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)`

only redirects to product detail view and doesn't add product directly to cart.

I also tried `$this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product)`

which also redirects to product detail view.

Anybody know whats the error?

Comment: which version of Magento are you using?

Comment: Magento Version 1.9.1.0

Comment: If the product is configurable product you will be redirected to product details page